# Using CSRF protection with a REST API with Sails.js

Tags: rest, sails.js, csrf

It says in the docs that:

> A would-be attacker needs not only a user's session cookie, but also
>   this timestamped, secret CSRF token, which is refreshed/granted when
>   the user visits a URL on your app's domain.

Does this mean that a new CSRF token is granted whenever you hit an API route? Or does any single client receive a CSRF token for life? When does Sails decide to grant a *different* token to the same client?

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF token that Sails generates is good for the lifetime of the session.  It's true that if an attacker was able to capture this token, they'd be able to use it to submit requests on your behalf.  But, if they had already compromised your system to the extent that they could eavesdrop on traffic between you and the server, they wouldn't need the CSRF token to impersonate you anyway, so it's a moot point.

Answer (score -2):

A new CSRF token is generated for each API request.

If you would generate a fixed token for each client, an attacker can easily capture it and the protection would be gone.

Comment: The token is secret between the client and the server. An attacker can't *easily* capture it although some systems will generate a new CSRF token for each request.

Comment: Doesn't this mean there are issues with asynchronous requests? If I made two requests within milliseconds, the second request would fail because of an invalid CSRF.

Comment: @Quentin Please read my Post again. AN attacker can easily capture it, only when you would generate a lifetime token for each client.

Comment: @Mario Just having done some testing, I have found that this isn't the case - I was able to use the same token for multiple requests, so the question remains: when does the token change?

Comment: @Mario — Not refreshing tokens regularly makes it *easier* to capture the token, but it doesn't make it easy.